# ListView from JSON Parse sometimes valid mostly null, whats going on?

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, reddit

So my problem is that my adapter seems to be throwing null exceptions for most of the data I parsed from a the JSON source http://www.reddit.com/r/hot/.json?sort=new&count=25.

What I've tried:
1. I've Logged all the objects being created from the parse to confirm that i got data.
2. I've wrapped the offending code in try catch statements to find out when it is working and when it is not.

What I've learned:
1. There is indeed data coming in from the .json document
2. The logic only seems to work for three of the rows in my list view the rest return null

I'm guessing perhaps some of the json queries are returning null, but I have no idea why.

**The Offending Code**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MainActivity.MyViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null){

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent,false);
        holder = new MainActivity.MyViewHolder();
        holder.listName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.authorName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        holder.thumbnail = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        holder.goButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.go_button);


    }else {
        holder = (MainActivity.MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    convertView.setOnClickListener(this);

    ListData data = topics.get(position);
    try {
Line81  holder.data = data;
        holder.listName.setText(data.getTitle());
        holder.authorName.setText(data.getAuthor());

        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Cell Created");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG,"Cell Not Created Due to: ",e);
    }

    if(data.getImageUrl()!=null){
        try {
   Line93   holder.thumbnail.setTag(data.getImageUrl());


            Drawable drawable = imgGet.loadImage(this, holder.thumbnail);
            if (drawable != null) {
                holder.thumbnail.setImageDrawable(drawable);

            } else {
                holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.filler_icon);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG,"no image: ",e);

        }

        return convertView;
```

**The Error Messages**

```
07-07 10:45:27.396    6606-6606/com.google.android.gms.redditviewr.app V/LOGTAG!!!﹕ Cell Not Created Due to:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Adapters.RedditDataAdapter.getView(RedditDataAdapter.java:81)

07-07 10:45:27.404    6606-6606/com.google.android.gms.redditviewr.app V/LOGTAG!!!﹕ no image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Adapters.RedditDataAdapter.getView(RedditDataAdapter.java:93)
```

**My JSON Parsing Logic**

```
try {
       JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray hotTopics = data.getJSONArray("children");
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, hotTopics.toString());
        for(int i=0; i<hotTopics.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject topic = hotTopics.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("data");
            ListData item = new ListData();
            item.setTitle(topic.getString("title"));
            item.setAuthor(topic.getString("author"));
            item.setImageUrl(topic.getString("thumbnail"));
            item.setPostTime(topic.getString("created_utc"));
            item.setrScore(topic.getString("score"));



                topicdata.add(item);
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG,topicdata.toString());
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.activity.setTopics(topicdata);

}
```

Comment: which lines correspond to 81 and 93?

Comment: 81---> holder.data = data;
           

   
      93---> holder.thumbnail.setTag(data.getImageUrl());

Comment: @EugenMartynov  whats the logic behind that?

Comment: You want to reuse it. But you don't save reference to holder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify this:

```
if (convertView == null){

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent,false);
        holder = new MainActivity.MyViewHolder();
        holder.listName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.authorName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        holder.thumbnail = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        holder.goButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.go_button);

}
```

To this:

```
if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent,false);

        holder = new MainActivity.MyViewHolder();
        holder.listName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.authorName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        holder.thumbnail = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        holder.goButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.go_button);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

}
```

Comment: Well you were totally right. Thanks! Unfortunately for me this only revealed another hole in my code though but you've squashed this specific bug.